# Several issues with opening android notification

Tags: android, push-notification

Hi all I have several isssues with my android notification. my code is the following:

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
        this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("at_now", true);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);


PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        intent, 0);


NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(name)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{500, 500, 1000})
                .setLights(Color.RED, 500, 1000)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
                                .setBigContentTitle(name)
                                .addLine(content_txt)
                                .addLine(mesagge)
                ).setContentText(content_txt);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());


Session.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getSharedPreferences().edit().putBoolean("REFRESHNOW",true).commit();
```

But it has several bugs.

1.) It opens every time new instance of the application if i do something and i get notification. Later when I close the app which was opened after clicking the notification, the previous screen appears, even if it is the same activity.

2.) if i recieve notification when my application is not opened it works fine. after i close the application I get back to my system menu. it is ok!

3.)When i opened application by clicking to notification, and if i get after another notification, it is no way it opens `MainActivity` it just bring forward the application, even if i am not in the main activity.

4.) the notification message does not disappear after clicking on it.

I have added these lines to my manifest as well:

```
android:noHistory="true"
android:launchMode = "singleTop"
```

5.)at main activity after opening it from intent i have extras like these : [image: extras]. So even the extras which i put to the intent does not work.

Answer (score 1):

In NotificationGcmIntentService class     use below code to clear notification .                                                                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
          mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

Comment: thank you it helped to clear the notification after clicking. i have upvoted you answer.